# Dismissing UIAlert window through Instruments script run through CLI

Tags: javascript, ios, instruments, xcode-instruments

When running an Instruments test suite through Instruments CLI, I'm unable to programatically dismiss a UIAlert window on the device that asks for push notification permissions for my app in test.  This is on the very first run of the app.  Since this permissions alert blocks the test script from running at all, my defined alert handler is also not called.

Running the suite through Instruments UI app calls the default alert handler, which taps the default button to successfully dismiss the alert.

How can I dismiss this alert programatically, if the script itself is blocked?
Is there a way to preset this permission, so the alert is not displayed?

Edit: this alert is ONLY in iOS 9; it does not pop up in iOS 8